"rise 2%" VS "rise at 2%" VS "rise by 2%"
I thought we can say only "verb + by + number" but I came across "verb + at + number" and "verb + number".
I got interested in whether there is any difference between them.

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com (item №3 -> Extra Examples):
(1) Tax receipts rose 2.5%.
my variants:
(2) Tax receipts rose at 2.5%.
(3) Tax receipts rose by 2.5%.
Are (2) and (3) correct?
If they are, then what's the difference between (1), (2) and (3)?
If not, then why not?

cambridge.org:
(4) Inflation is rising at 2.1 percent a month.
(5) Inflation is rising by 2.1 percent a month.
my variant:
(6) Inflation is rising 2.1 percent a month.
Is (6) correct?
If it is, then what's the difference between (4), (5) and (6)?
If not, then why not?

The examples aren't 100% compatible. I don't see Tax receipts rose at 2.5% in oxfordlearners anyway, and Inflation is rising at 2.1 percent a month from cambridge is "peculiar". If inflation really did "rise" by 2.1% a month, that would mean the inflation rate would go up by well over 25% a year (compound interest), but it's highly unlikely anyone would actually say that. Inflation is already a "rate of increase" before it starts "rising" - unlike tax receipts, which are just an annual total with no "built-in" annual increase.

@FumbleFingers +1 and 25% annual inflation isn't common in Western economies, but somewhere like Turkey, it's normal. "Turkey inflation rate for 2022 was 72.31%, a 52.71% increase from 2021." link

"... rose x%" and "... rose by x%" always mean exactly the same thing: The new number is x% higher than the old number.
"*... rose at x%", however, is ambiguous, at least in writing. The "at" could refer to the number itself, or to the percentage it rose.
Your sentence (2) could be rewritten in present perfect:

(2a) At 2.5%, tax receipts have risen.
OR
(2b) Tax receipts have risen at a rate of 2.5%.

2a means tax receipts have risen, because now they're 2.5%, and presumably they were lower before. 2b has the expected meaning.
Both of these could be expressed as:

(2c) Tax receipts have risen at 2.5%.

To me, 2b is quite natural, and 2a is less natural, and would do better with a comma before "at".

You wrote: "(2a) means tax receipts have risen, because now they're 2.5%, and presumably they were lower before." — Do you mean that (2a) means "Tax receipts have risen to 2.5%"? Thanks.

@Loviii Yes, that's it.

If something is rising at 2.5%, the rate is currently 2.5% but it is rising (it was maybe 2.4% last month and 2.3% the month before that). If inflation is falling at 2.5% then it's still 2.5% but it's less than last month (2.6%).
If something is rising by 2.5%, then if the base value is a percentage (e.g. the interest rate is 20%) then you add on 2.5% e.g. from 20% to 22.5% - sometimes this is expressed as "rising by 2.5 percentage points" (although sometimes people, even reporters, get confused by this, so be careful). If it's a numerical quantity, it's increasing so that new = old * (1 + percentage), e.g. from 100 metres to 102.5 metres (old * 1.025).
If something rises 2.5% then it's the same as "rises by 2.5%" - depending on whether it's a percentage changing, or a numerical value.
You need to be careful because a lot of people don't understand percentages, confusing the new value with the difference, the ratio between two values with the percentage difference between the two, etc. It helps if you know what is being measured, the units, and the likely value, e.g. inflation in the US is typically between 0 and 10% per annum; income tax might be 20%-80% of gross income; the ratio of men to women is a percentage but the number of men is a numerical value; etc.

You wrote: "If something is rising at 2.5%, the rate is currently 2.5% but it is rising (it was maybe 2.4% last month and 2.3% the month before that). If inflation is falling at 2.5% then it's still 2.5% but it's less than last month (2.6%)." — Does this mean that "at" means "to" here, i.e. "to rise/fall at 2.5%" = "to rise/fall to 2.5%"? Thanks.
